# Дубликаты в ArrayList без перебора

Tags: java

Есть вот такая задачка:
Написать метод, который находит дубликаты объектов в ArrayList, без использование поэлементного перебора.

Не прошу решить задачку за меня. Прошу подкинуть идею, в какую сторону копать надо.
с использованием поэлементного перебора - делается легко. а вот как без?

Comment: Тоже стало любопытно. Но такие задачи вызывают недоумение... Мол используется список, это такая коллекция элементов, но вы решите задачу без перебора по элементам :D Это как "есть пианино, на нем играют руками, но вы сыграйте жопой" :D

Comment: @gil9red конечно это задачка - извращение, которое никогда не пригодится в жизни. но интересно решить!)

Comment: А мне непонятно что значит «без использование поэлементного перебора». Мне же по любому нужно весь список обойти?

Comment: возможно, имелось ввиду - не перебирать самому? Что-то типа `myList.stream().collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());` вернее, сперва - так, а потом найти расхождения исходного списка и этого (обратная операция к пересечению множеств, забыл как называется, а гуглить лень)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Узнал точное решение, которое хотел преподаватель.
Оно основывается на компараторах.
Показываю решение на примере `ArrayList<Integer>`, но конечно это можно сделать для любого дженериков.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(5);
arrayList.add(5);
arrayList.add(5);
arrayList.add(7);
arrayList.add(9);
arrayList.add(0);
arrayList.add(7);
Log.e("!!!!", "" + arrayList);


Sorted s = new Sorted();
arrayList.sort(s);
arrayList = s.fin();
Log.e("!!!!", "" + arrayList);
```

Sorted.class

```
public class Sorted implements Comparator<Integer> {

    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        if (o1 > o2) return 1;
        else if (o1 < o2) return -1;
        else if (o1 == o2 && !arr.contains(o2)) {
            arr.add(o2);
            return 0;
        } else return 0;

    }


    public ArrayList<Integer> fin() {
        return arr;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Совсем без перебора не получится.

Нужно создать `Set` и перебрать все элементы проверяя их наличие в `Set`: если нет, то добавить; если уже есть, то дубликат найден.

```
        var list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1);
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        List<Integer> result = list.stream()
                .filter(e -> !set.add(e))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

Comment: ну я думаю, что те, кто создал задачку, знают способ "без перебора")

Comment: Это невозможно в принципе. Нужно посмотреть все элементы.

Comment: @Wlad  `знают способ "без перебора")` возможно,имеется в виду метод, когда для каждого элемента ищутся дубликаты перебором  оставшихся - т.е. два вложенных цикла

Comment: преподаватель сказал "можно без перебора. никаких циклов". =(

Comment: @Wlad добавил реализацию "без циклов"

Answer (score 0):

Для поднятия актива выкину свое решение.
Не знаю, на сколько оно правильное, ведь я перебираю 1 раз все уникальные значения в массиве.

UPD!
Показал код преподу. Он сказал "можно сделать без циклов. никаких переборов. думайте в сторону Set".

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

arrayList.add(5);
arrayList.add(5);
arrayList.add(5);
arrayList.add(7);
arrayList.add(9);
arrayList.add(0);
arrayList.add(7);
Log.e("!!!!", "" + arrayList);
arrayList = sort(arrayList);
Log.e("!!!", "" + arrayList);






public <T> ArrayList<T> sort(ArrayList<T> arrayList) {


 ArrayList<T> arr_final = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<T> buff = new ArrayList<>();

 while (arrayList.size() != 0) {
    T a = arrayList.get(0);
    arrayList.remove(0);
    if (arrayList.contains(a)) {
        arr_final.add(a);
        buff.add(a);
        arrayList.removeAll(buff);
        buff.clear();
    }

}

return arr_final;

}
```

Comment: Ну это не только перебор с квадратичным временем, но и неоправданное удаление, что приводит к дополнительным затратам времени